# Tomcat Web Application Access Error

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, html

I have an Web Application running on Tomcat, port 8080.
  When I access it with "**http://localhost:8080/AppName**", I get a "page contains secure and nonsecure items" warning and the page loads properly.
    But when I access with "**http://10.200.200.20:8080/AppName**", I do not get the "page contains secure and nonsecure items" warning and the page doesn't load at all.
    There are no https item in the welcome page nor iFrame. But there is an Ajax Call for WebService in that page.  I'm not sure why I get this error. Please share your thoughts on it.

Thanks,
SKR

Comment: Is `10.200.200.20` your own IP address and are you accessing the web-app from another machine or your own? Are you testing from a browser that you haven't set any special security settings/exceptions? Have you setup your tomcat to use SSL on port 8080?

Comment: 10.200.200.20 is my own IP address. I'm accessing the web-app from my own machine. The same browser is used for both tests. SSL port is not enabled on 8080.

Comment: I suspect this is a (outdated) browser quirk. Try the app from a different browser(avoid Internet Explorer) and also ensure tomcat is not giving you useful information in the logs.

Comment: I am using IE-8 Running on Windows 7. This enterprise application is supposed to support / work for IE-6 and IE-8. It doesn't load in Firefox or Chrome at all.